# How do I set resources in XAML on a WPF component that already has resources?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I have created a UserControl with a DataGrid that has defined resources for its internal workings:

```
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button x:Name="ExcelFilterButton"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        Click="ExcelFilterButton_Click"
                                        Focusable="False"
                                        Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                                        Tag="{Binding}">
                                    <Image Width="19"
                                           Height="19"
                                           Source="Resources\NoSortNoFilter.png"
                                           Tag="{Binding}" />
                                </Button>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Text="{Binding}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Now, while trying to use the component in an application and setting some colors with the following XAML

```
                            <adg:AdvancedSortFilterDataGrid.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" />
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColor}" />                                   
                            </adg:AdvancedSortFilterDataGrid.Resources>
```

Gets me the following error at runtime:

```
'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.' Line number '200' and line position '34'.
```

I tried to use a Resources property in the component to just add the resources to the existing resources, but get the same error. Here's the property:

```
Public Shadows Property Resources As ResourceDictionary
    Get
        Return dataGrid.Resources
    End Get
    Set(value As ResourceDictionary)
        For Each Key As Object In value.Keys
            dataGrid.Resources.Add(Key, value(Key))
        Next
    End Set
End Property
```

Hoping someone can set me straight.

EDIT: InnerException:

```
Cannot re-initialize ResourceDictionary instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems I found the answer on StackOverflow. Don't know why I didn't find these in my initial search. Anyway, I found that if I put the resources inside a ResourcesDictionary element in both the component and the using application, and put the ResourcesDictionary element inside a MergedDictionaries element in the component, it works fine.

Component:

```
       <DataGrid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Button x:Name="ExcelFilterButton"
                                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                                    Click="ExcelFilterButton_Click"
                                                    Focusable="False"
                                                    Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                                                    Tag="{Binding}">
                                                <Image Width="19"
                                                       Height="19"
                                                       Source="Resources\NoSortNoFilter.png"
                                                       Tag="{Binding}" />
                                            </Button>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                       Text="{Binding}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Using Application:

```
                           <adg:AdvancedSortFilterDataGrid.Resources>
                                <ResourceDictionary>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" />
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColor}" />
                                </ResourceDictionary>
                            </adg:AdvancedSortFilterDataGrid.Resources>
```

And I changed the Resources Property in the component to add the new ResourcesDictionary to the MergedDictionaries.

```
Public Shadows Property Resources As ResourceDictionary
    Get
        If dataGrid.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Count < 2 Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Return dataGrid.Resources.MergedDictionaries(1)
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As ResourceDictionary)
        Do Until dataGrid.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Count = 1
            dataGrid.Resources.MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(1)
        Loop
        dataGrid.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Now it works fine. It was just too simple to see.